# How to log iptables as of kernel 3.9.0?

Tags: linux-kernel, iptables

What is the right way to log iptables as of kernel 3.9.0?

I can no longer append a logging rule such as:

```
# iptables --new-chain droplog
# iptables --append droplog --jump LOG --log-level info
iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.
```

I used to enable IP tables logging support by checking this out:

```
IP: Netfilter Configuration  --->
 <*> IP tables support (required for filtering/masq/NAT)
    <*> LOG target support
```

But this option is missing from kernel 3.9.0, and seems to have been replaced by `CONFIG_NETFILTER_NETLINK_LOG`.

Answer (score 2):

The symbol that enables the `LOG` target has changed to `NETFILTER_XT_TARGET_LOG`. Its location has also moved to:

```
Networking support
 Networking options
  Network packet filtering framework (Netfilter)
   Core Netfilter Configuration
    Netfilter Xtables support (required for ip_tables)
     LOG target support
```

If we could just track how kernel symbols change over time, that would be great.